# PHP isset function is not working to print data

Tags: php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST">

    <input type="text" name="text">
    <input type="button" value="Check" name="submit">
</form>
<p>
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

$a=$_POST['text'];
    echo "You have written" . $a;
}


?></p>


    
</body>
</html>
```

I am using PHP isset function here in this html form, but don't know why it is not echoing anything. It should print the text written inside the input box. Please help me why this is not working?

Comment: hi, you did not specify the action as <form method="POST" action="youraction.php"> see https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Answer (score 2):

To submit the form, you need to use `submit` type for button, not `button`:

```
<input type="submit" value="Check" name="submit">
```

Tested, changing the type resolves your issue.